# Heat equation for a 3d vector

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The heat equation is equal to: $$ \partial T/ \partial t - \alpha^2\nabla^2 T = 0 $$
for scalar $T(\mathbf x,t)$, the general solution to this differential equation can easily be found by taking a Fourier transform on T.
$$ T(\mathbf x,t)    \to T(\mathbf\omega,t) $$
Now what would it be if $T$ was a 3D vector aka: $T=T(x,y,z)$
What's the general solution to this differential equation:
$$ \partial \mathbf T/ \partial t - \alpha^2\nabla^2 \mathbf T = 0 $$